# How to solve a system of equations with indexed variables in SymPy?

Tags: python, sympy

I have a system of equations with indexed variables. What I want is to solve the dynamic function of one variable and cancel another. For example:

```py
from sympy import symbols, IndexedBase, Eq, solve

t = symbols('t', interger=True)
β = symbols('β')
c, λ = symbols('c λ', cls=IndexedBase)

eq1=Eq(c[t],λ[t])
eq2=Eq(λ[t],β*λ[t+1])

solve([eq1,eq2],[c[t],c[t+1]])
```

I get the result: `{c[t]: λ[t]}`. It is right, but what I really want is a function to show the relationship between `c[t]` and `c[t+1]` like `c[t+1]=f(c[t])` (without `λ[t]`). Here, the result should be `c[t+1]=1/β*c[t]`.

What should I do? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `solve` function is not intended to handle situations like this. It's purpose is to solve algebraic equations and so anything like `c[t]` and `c[t+1]` are just treated as independent algebraic variables.

You can get what you want using `resultant` though:

```
In [15]: from sympy import symbols, IndexedBase, Eq, solve
    ...: 
    ...: t = symbols('t', interger=True)
    ...: β = symbols('β')
    ...: c, λ = symbols('c λ', cls=IndexedBase)
    ...: 
    ...: eq1=Eq(c[t],λ[t])
    ...: eq2=Eq(λ[t],β*λ[t+1])

In [16]: resultant(eq1, eq2, λ[t])
Out[16]: β⋅λ[t + 1] - c[t]

In [17]: resultant(resultant(eq1, eq2, λ[t]), eq1.subs(t, t+1), λ[t + 1])
Out[17]: β⋅c[t + 1] - c[t]

In [18]: solve(_, c[t+1], dict=True)
Out[18]: 
⎡⎧          c[t]⎫⎤
⎢⎨c[t + 1]: ────⎬⎥
⎣⎩           β  ⎭⎦
```